# Retreiving BCH from addr appearing on both BTC and BCH blockchains

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin

I have an address (`1LeuGn7xjF9UdCn2YEHyJ4izWDmynZgC8E`) that I've been using for BTC and for which I have the passphrase and wallet file. It looks like I also got BCH sent to `qrte263mhwmyhpzmkry7qvkky75g5nq2evdr7cc505` , an address for which I don't seem to have the passphrase.
But if I check `1Leu...` on a blockchain explorer its listed as occurring on 2 blockchains (BTC and BCH, with some coins in the BCH part) and indeed the `qrte263...` addr is listed as the 'cash address format' on the BCH blockchain for a 'legacy address format' of `1Leu...`

My question is - given that I have the passphrase for 1Leu, can I/how do I retrieve the BCH from this address. I've tried copay and exodus imports so far to no avail - copay does not like the 13-word phrase and exodus says "unable to move funds - there is nothing to move from `1JGDhcoR2Q7ZHxT1wEvZxb6jvX1ZLVCNqq`" when I try 'move funds' using a WIF private key generated with `btc_address_dump "<BTC_passphrase>"`.
(Incidentally `1JGD...` is listed as a legacy address (p2pkh compressed) by the btc_address_dump tool.)

Possibly, exodus is only checking the BTC blockchain and not the BCH blockchain. Can anyone advise?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For anyone in a similar pickle, I solved this by using the last 12 words of the 13-word phrase I had saved after having tried various combinations of import options and passphrase subsets.  The `btc_address_dump` tool was helpful.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [BitCash](https://pybitcash.github.io/bitcash/) to create a wallet from the private key:

Install it first:

```sh
pip install bitcash
```

then

```py
from bitcash import Key

k = Key('your_wif_or_other_private_key_format')
k.get_balance()
k.send([('your_new_BCH_address', 2000, 'satoshi')], leftover='your_new_BCH_address')
```

Comment: Thanks this helped track down the killer.